# "The member's email address is not allowed for this project. Check with your administrator" when adding a partner to a project where I am Mantainer

Tags: permissions, gitlab

I am trying to add a colleague to a GitLab project of the company where I am Maintainer but I have problems adding the user to a project:

1. I go to my project and select `Project information > Members`.
2. In the `Invite member` tab, under GitLab member or Email address, enter the user name or email address.
3. I select a role.

And I send it but I get a reply from GitLab that:

```
The member's email address is not allowed for this project. Check with your administrator.
```

What should the administrator do?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the domain of your colleague's email is restricted using [Restrict group access by domain](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/access_and_permissions.html#restrict-group-access-by-domain) feature.

> What should the administrator do?

They should go to `Settings > General` and verify that `Restrict membership by email` field contains the correct set of domains.